# "Senkenden Hauptes schlief sie langsam ein" — is this grammatically correct?

Tags: german-to-english, grammaticality

Especially I would like to know when this is a correct complete German sentence:

- What type of grammatical structure do the first two words belong to?
- Is it common to speak that way? I refer to the grammatical structure of the first 2 words. (Sounds like from the Middle Ages.)
- Can you translate the original sentence into English as shortly as possible?

<sub>[Are there more ways in German to abbreviate a subordinate clause by use of a participle?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/ways-in-german-to-abbreviate-a-subordinate-clause-by-use-of-a-particple) (Would *während sie das Haupt senkte, schlief sie langsam ein* be a correct alternative?) This part was exported to a new question.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grammatical structure you're looking for is the *modaler Genitiv*, which is a type of modal adverbial. These are mostly set phrases such as

> erhobenen Hauptes, schweren Herzens, ruhigen Gewissens, stehenden Fußes.

For a detailed study see the dissertation [*Adverbiale Kasus des Deutschen*](http://d-nb.info/981292224/34), pages 122–135.

---

As for the grammatical correctness of the sentence, the verb *senken* can be used transitive or reflexiv, so both

> Er senkte *das Haupt*

and

> Der Brustkorb hebt und senkt *sich* (from [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/senken#Bedeutung3a))

are grammatically correct. If you google for *senkenden*, then you'll see that it's used in very different circumstances, e.g.,

> Mit *Kosten* senkenden Maßnahmen wurde der Betrieb gerettet.

Here, the *costs* are lowered. In contrast,

> senkenden Hauptes

doesn't say what is lowered: The thing that is lowered should stand in the Akkusativ, while *Hauptes* is Genitiv.

**Conclusion:** *senkenden Hauptes schlief sie ein* is semantically impossible, and probably also grammatically not correct.

Comment: thx for your effort. I dont understand why *Erhobenen Hauptes geht er aus der die Wohnung* is ok but *Senkenden Hauptes* is wrong according to your reasoning, it sounds uncommon, i agree, but it seem grammatically correct or at least common http://www.google.com/search?q=%22erhobenen+hauptes+geht%22&ie=UTF-8 I still dont know what type of grammatical structure this is, it would probably shed a lot of light onto the grammatical/semantic correctness...but we are approaching the answer :). Also *mit Kosten senkenden Mass.* has a different function than *erhobenen Hauptes*, basically a sub. clause

Comment: @Hauser: _Erhobenen Hauptes_ is correct, no question. As I wrote in another comment, _gesenkten Hauptes_ is also correct. (And _this_ is the opposite of _erhobenen Hauptes!_)

Comment: Agree, its the opposite, but whats then the rule? **It must be a state not a present action that the participle describes?**

Comment: @Hauser: See my updated answer.

Comment: The answer doesn't mention the obvious and important difference between 'senken' (aktiv) and 'sinken' (passiv) which is the first level of error. If such a sentence should be attempted, then by using 'sinkenden Hauptes'.

Comment: @markus: No, my answer doesn't (fully) address this point, and this is for the simple reason that it had been mentioned in previous answers already. Is this already a reason for downvoting my answer? `:-(` By the way, I did address the point partially by pointing out clearly that 'senken' is transitive. (And I'd say that also 'sinkenden Hauptes' is _semantically_ not allowed unless you're a famous poet.)

Comment: +1 dear @HendrikVogt, perfect explanation!

Answer (score 5):

I’m unsure, but it sounds wrong to me:

> “Senkenden Hauptes schlief sie langsam ein.”

instead:

> “Sinkenden Hauptes schlief sie langsam ein.”

or:

> “Das Haupt senkend, schlief sie langsam ein.”

In einem Zugabteil, wo man dem langsamen Sinken zusehen kann, finde ich die Formulierung durchaus angebracht, auch wenn *Haupt* sehr feierlich klingt, und durch *Kopf* gut ersetzt werden kann, wenn das nicht gewünscht ist.

English attempt:

> “Lowering her head, she fell asleep.”

Comment: How can *senkenden Hauptes* be wrong, but *sinkenden Hauptes* be correct - it would be the same grammatical structure? It are still her muscles lowering the head, you can argue if it is a active but unconscious(senken) or passive(sinken) process imo? Thx for the english translation, **is there a option of expressing this in english without comma & subordinate clause?**

Comment: I can't cite rules, but 'senkenden' would, imho, work in a sentence like 'Senkenden Hauptes wurde der Hund eingeschläfert', when both parts are passiv.

Comment: @Hauser: Because, how else should I express the situation? "Sie schlief, das Haupt sinken lassend, ein". But not "Sie schlief, das Haupt senken lassed, ein". Sie senkt das Haupt, das Haupt wird gesenkt, das Haupt sank. Sehenden Auges habe ich mich auf die Diskussion eingelassen. Es fehlt ein mit? "Mit sinkendem Haupt schlief sie ein." Man schreibt ja auch nicht "Wehender Fahnen zogen sie ins Stadion" oder "Tränender Augen lasen sie abstruse Beispiele im Netz."

Comment: @hendrik following your reasoning above i would think now `Sinkenden Hauptes schlief...Mit sinkenden Haupt` is correct as not transitive/reflexive!?

Comment: `... mit sinkendem Haupt` sinkende**m**. But is it transitive or reflexive? I'm sorry ...

Answer (score 3):

<strike>From a grammatical point of view it's a correct expression</strike> As Hendrik pointed out in the comments of this answer, it's neither a grammatically nor a semantically correct expression. The verb "senken" is transitive and requires an object.

The common German idiom you're looking for is

> mit gesenktem Haupt(e) ...

The phrase for the opposite meaning

> erhobenen Hauptes ...

is formed using the genitive case though.

Both idioms are not day-to-day expressions, but they're not outdated.

Comment: yeah *erhobenen Hauptes* gives a lot google hits, but im still looking for the exact terminus of this grammatical structure using a particple...

Comment: Maybe one should point out that "senkenden Hauptes" is for sure not _semantically_ correct. Is it grammatically correct? I'm not sure, "senken" is either transitive or reflexive!

Comment: @splattne: The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that "senkenden Hauptes schlief sie ein" is not even _grammatically_ correct since the Objekt for "senkenden" is missing.

Comment: @Hendrik You're right. *senken* is a transitive verb, so only "Das Haupt senkend" would be a grammatically right. Nice catch! I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic expression:

> Sein Haupt senken

is used to depict a gesture of humility (similar to *"seinen Blick senken"*).

It is not - at least not commonly - used in the context of falling asleep where the expression *"ihr Kopf [Haupt] sinkt nieder"* would be more appropriate (*"Kopf"* would be a more modern synonym of *"Haupt"*).

Comment: sry was a bit inexact probably, i meant if it is common to use this type of grammatical structure - *senkenden hauptes*. But you are right, *haupt* is a bit old stlye, while *erhobenen Hauptes* you imo still find in current novels(?).

Comment: @Hauser: _gesenkten Hauptes_ is also quite OK.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I disagree for the context with falling asleep.  ["Gesenkten Hauptes"](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/gesenkten+Hauptes) is a synonym to *"kleinlaut"*, *"beschämt"*. Of course you could go to bed *ashamed* - but I doubt very much that this is meant in the context above.

Comment: @Takkat: I only meant to say that it's common to say _gesenkten Hauptes_. I didn't mean to imply any context.

Answer (score 2):

In German: "sinken" and "senken" is not the same. It' offtopic but maybe you should check that first :-)

Maybe you could write something like: "Ihr Kopf fiel nach vorne, sie schlief einfach ein." or so...

In addition to that: In German you have to use commas to seperate main clause from subordinate clause. I don't know how good your German is but maybe this could help: [Nebensätze](http://mein-deutschbuch.de/grammatik/saetze/nebensaetze.pdf). If you don't get along I can give further explanations...

Comment: Hi sarah and welcome here. thx for your answer, but i was aware of this, look at my comment on users anwers. You would also say *senkenden Zeigefingers schloss er seine Drohung ab*? The main question is what tpye of grammatical structure this is and how to say the same without using a subordinate clause.

Comment: @sarah thx, im aware of your edited information. The question is not how to transform the sentence but what type of grammatical structure this is and the shortest translation into english. Im exactly looking for NOT using a subordinate clause and comma to make it as short as possible in one clause without loosing meaning :)

Comment: @Hauser: You wouldn't say _senkenden Zeigefingers_; I claim that it's semantically impossible, and I think it's not even grammatically correct.