# How can we abbreviate a subordinate clause by use of a participle?

Tags: sentence-structure, participle

In [another question](//german.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/senkenden-hauptes-schlief-sie-langsam-ein-is-this-grammatically-correct), I asked for the grammaticality of:

> Senkenden Hauptes schlief sie langsam ein.

which may be a possible, uncommon abbreviation of

> Während sie das Haupt senkte, schlief sie langsam ein.

Here, I am asking what other options one has in German to abbreviate a subordinate clause by use of participle structures. Maybe you give out a terminus for the grammatical structure and a short example?

Comment: I think it is more an abbreviation of 'Während sich ihr Haupt senkte, schlief sie langsam ein.' When you start sleeping  your possibilities to do things actively are very limited.

Comment: @bernd you can also take the example *Erhobenen Zeigefingers formulierte er seine Drohung*. Thats interchangeable and not the main point driving this question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In German it's a bit different, I try to compare my language and yours :-D

#### In English you can use the participle for this, make two to one:

> I saw the girl yesterday. She went down the stairs. ➜ I saw the girl going down the stairs...

- In German the same could be done by using a *Relativsatz* or a *Infinitivkonstruktion*, e.g.:

  > *Gestern sah ich das Mädchen. Sie ging die Treppe hinunter. ➜ Ich sah das Mädchen die Treppe hinuntergehen.*
- Especially after sensory verbs, you could use different type of subordinate clauses in German:

  > *Ich sah, wie das Mädchen die Treppe hinunterging.*

#### In addition to that you can use the participle to eliminate subordinate clauses:

> As she went to the principal she was angry. ➜ Going to the principal she was angry.

- In German you can use ***Partizip I*** and ***II***:

  > *Indem sie ein fröhliches Liedchen pfeift, erledigt Yanina ihre Hausaufgaben. ➜
  >   Ein fröhliches Liedchen pfeifend, erledigt Yanina ihre Hausaufgaben.* **(Partizip I)**
  >
  > *Als wir am Schwerter Bahnhof ankamen, nahmen wir sofort ein Taxi. ➜
  >   Am Schwerter Bahnhof angekommen, nahmen wir sofort in ein Taxi.* **(Partizip II)**

For further reading: [Participles](http://www.ego4u.de/de/cram-up/grammar/participles) [Partizip I and II](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Nebensaetze.htm)

Some examples from: http://www.english-work.com

Comment: Oh I see, in an instant it's done :)

Comment: :)) thx again. I'm totally new here. Next time I'll format it :))

Comment: +1 great anwer and self introduction. How did you came upon this site? We need more german women ;)