# A phrase list for the curious case of the "Genitivus Absolutus"?

Tags: phrase-request, genitive

[Hendrik's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1999/1224) on [my question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1990/1224) brought me back to the feared and famous Ablativus Absolutus (at least on my school mates). [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablativus_absolutus#.C3.84hnliche_Konstruktionen) states that there are relics of it named as Genitivus Absolutus.

> stehenden Fußes, klopfenden Herzens...

But they are declared as *stehende Ausdrücke*. That means, imho, you can use the known ones and only the known ones, but you are not allowed/animated to build new ones yourself like *sinkenden Hauptes*, which would be same grammatical structure as above examples.

In English it actually seems you are allowed to do this in form of the [Nominative absolute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute) with any noun and participle.

So, is there a at most complete list of these German *stehenden Ausdrücke* you can use? Or maybe we can just put links/examples here in a CW-answer? I'm a true lover of the *Genitiv* and *Ablativus Absolutus*. :)

Comment: Ablativus Absolutus, thank you for bringing me back to school as well ;) Shouldn't it be "feststehende Ausdrücke", by the way? Interesting question anyway.

Comment: Does "zu jemandes Lebzeiten" belong here, or is that expression different somehow?

Comment: The language wasn't a gift from a god, but has been produced by former generations. What is a 'feststehender Ausdruck' today was new in the past. So I don't see, how somebody could prohibit us to invent new expressions, which will be fixed in 2 or 3 generations.

Comment: @user no gift?! Come on, i enjoyed reading Asterix in Latin :) You can probably not prohibit new inventing, but the Genitiv seems to have a very Middle Ages touch to most. Proof may be `Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod` :)

Comment: @oregon would be interested to know how many Latin Lovers we have here :) Good chance to remind on the Latin proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21061/latin-language-usage i fear that i have totally forgot most of it in some years... :( A Q&A site would really be the right method to prevent this

Comment: @Hauser: I also forgot a lot of it, though the knowledge that's still there greatly complements usage of European languages of today :)

Answer (score 7):

Here are some expressions which are often used in German:

**Expressing a mental or emotional state**

*ruhigen Gewissens*

> Markus gab seine Doktorarbeit ruhigen Gewissens ab.

*heiteren Gemütes*

> Heiteren Gemütes betrat die Lehrerin das Klassenzimmer.

*schweren Herzens*

> Schweren Herzens verließ der alte Mann sein Haus und zog ins Altersheim.

*guten Glaubens*

> Frau Mayer hatte die Wertpapiere, die später nichts mehr wert waren, guten Glaubens gekauft.

*frischen Mutes* oder *frohen Mutes*

> Frischen Mutes begab sich Karl auf die dreitätige Wanderung.

**Expressing how you do something**

*sehenden Auges* (leichtsinnig; obwohl man die Gefahr kommen sieht)

> Sehenden Auges fuhr Hans mit seinem Auto gegen die Mauer.

*erhobenen Hauptes*

> Die unterlegene Mannschaft, die sich tapfer geschlagen hatte, verließ das Spielfeld erhobenen Hauptes.

**Expressing other circumstances**

*unverrichteter Dinge*

> Da das Fernsehteam keine Drehgenehmigung bekommen hatte, musste es das Land unverrichteter Dinge wieder verlassen.

**As adverbial indication added to a sentence**

*meines Erachtens* oder *meines Wissens*

> Meines Wissens siedet Wasser auf 5000 m Meereshöhe bei ca. 80 °C.

*des Weiteren*

> Des Weiteren verlange ich den Rücktritt von Trainer Müller.

*seines/ihres Zeichens*

> Die Rede hielt Frau Gruber, ihres Zeichens Goldschmiedin.

*leider Gottes*

> Leider Gottes muss ich jetzt aufhören.

Comment: Also "frohen Mutes"

Comment: @pyvi thanks! updated the answer. btw, it's a community wiki, so feel free to edit and change this answer.

Comment: Oh, didn't see CW line. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the declaration of *stehende Ausdrücke.* When I read *sinkenden Hauptes* up there not only did I immediately have the correct picture in my head but also a sentence suggested itself to me immediately for how to use it:

> Sinkenden Hauptes verneigte sich die Titanic ein letztes Mal vor dem Eisberg.

If anything, I would say that the usage of these be rare and/or elevated but I don’t believe in an exhaustive list.

Comment: Vollkommen Off-Topic, aber ich  kann's nicht lassen: Dein schön poetischer Satz ist sachlich nicht ganz richtig - Da die Titanic am Eisberg vorbeigeschrammt und sich die Seite aufgeschlitzt hat, muss sie beim Sinken mit dem Heck zum Eisberg gestanden sein. Sie hat ihm also zum Abschied den Hintern gezeigt... Es muss also eher *erhobenen Hinterns* heißen, was nicht ganz so poetisch, aber m.A. nach grammatikalisch gleich zulässig ist.