# Why is "festen Schrittes" used instead of "mit festen Schritten"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case

This is the sentence from "Die Verwandlung".

> Aber dann ging natürlich wie immer das Dienstmädchen （*festen Schrittes*） zur Tür und öffnete.

Are the words in the bracket genitive or dative, plural or single? Why does the sentence use "festen Schrittes" instead of "mit festen Schritten" ？

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/a-phrase-list-for-the-curious-case-of-the-genitivus-absolutus, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/senkenden-hauptes-schlief-sie-langsam-ein-is-this-grammatically-correct

Comment: It is genitive and singular. _Mit festem Schritt_ wouldn’t be impossible either, although _festen Schrittes_ is a common collocation.

Comment: Also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/der-dativ-ist-dem-genitiv-sein-tod-is-german-really-losing-genitiv-evolutio

Comment: This basically deals with the same grammatical structure hence why I am labelling it as a duplicate.

Comment: Es gibt einige gängige Adverbien in Form eines Genitivs. Der übliche Begriff dafür ist "adverbialer Genitiv". Solche Formeln sind eher literarisch. Ich habe auch keine Idee, wie man solche Genitive herleitet. - http://gymbasis.ch/moodle/Deutsch/Grammatik/SG-Funktion/adverbialien.html

Comment: wieder ein Bsp., dass der Genitiv des Aussterbens ist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if "why" is a good question. Anyway, there are many phrases using the genetive singular in a similar manner:

> leichten/schweren/klopfenden Herzens
>
> guten Mutes
>
> allen Ernstes

I daresay they all describe the "mode" of doing something.

For me as a very oldfashioned native speaker it is absolutely natural to somewhat freely form phrases of this kind:

> Zornigen Blickes nahm er seinen Hut und verliess das Zimmer.

But the number of combinations that sound native is very limited. I would never say:

> Schweren Armes hob er sein Schwert.

It would be good to know if this ever was standard practise. I tend to assume that.